# Angular - replacing jQuery

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to use Anuglar over jQuery in my code and am starting the painful transition.

In my AppComponent I have this:

HTML:

```html
 <div class="login-wrapper toggle-content">
    <button class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
     <iframe
        id="loginframe"
        [src]="framesrc"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
      >Loading...</iframe>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```javascript
/* --------- Login widget toggle ----------- */
$(document).on('click', '#loginButton', function () {

  console.log("loginButton clicked");
  if (can3rdparty) {
    $('.toggle-content').slideToggle();
  } else {
    var popup = window.open(this.framesrc, '_blank', 'height=500,width=900');
  }
});
```

How do I use pure Angular/JavaScript for this?

Comment: Did you create a module and a controller using angular

Comment: Hi Yes - I am using Angular-CLI. The above is in app.compontents.ts. I have been struggling to get JQuery  to play nicely with NG2 so have given up with that and am going to try and learn an alternative way to work.

Comment: Wait, are you using Angular 2 or AngularJS 1? Because you've tagged this with `angularjs`, which is for AngularJS 1...

Comment: Angular and jQuery are not overlapping frameworks.  Angular is a framework for managing data and representing the data in HTML, while jQuery is a framework to assist with DOM Manipulation.  Even though Angular does perform some DOM Manipulation in order to work, that doesn't mean that it can replace jQuery.  You'll need to be quite a bit more detailed in describing what you are trying to accomplish, since you will likely have to re-think your design entirely in the context of Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button #viewChildHandle (click)="myFunction" class="close" type="button"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
```

in your controller class you will need to get a handle on your element using the @ViewChild annotation. Then when you have the handle you can wrap the viewChild element with jQuery just like you would wrap a normal HTML element with jQuery.

```
myFunction() {
   $(viewChildEl).slideToggle();
}
```